# Animation not working for UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, delete-row

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This code (in the method commitEditingStyle) is not making any changes in animation when a row is deleted. The row gets deleted, everything else running well, except for the animation.

Whatever I change the animation style to, it just wipes the text from left to right, simultaneously removing the row by moving upwards. And the very last row does a strange thing too. It wipes the text and removes the row, but not simultaneously like the rows about.

Is this the default behavior in iOS 7? I'm not understanding why this is so.

P.S. I don't know why but insertRowsAtIndexPaths animation seems to work fine.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Comment: I too want to know about this issue...

Comment: I think this is due to the sequence of removal. First you need to update (or in other words remove the element from) the collection that is being loaded to the table and then call the remove.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - regardless of what animation one chooses, it always does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 [self.tableView beginUpdates];

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Make also sure that the data source for your table view is in sync with what happens to the tableView.

I usually have an array as a data source and I overwrite its setter, that way it's allways on sync.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help.. Still does the weird thing it does